# MFC Application font issues - dialogs look wrongon Win2k8

Tags: winapi, user-interface, mfc

My legacy application that runs on win2k3 citrix is about to be migrated to win2k8 citrix.

While testing on win2k8 I noticed UI issues that are not apparent on 2k3 - buttons are not wide enough for their labels, text fields are truncated, etc.

I noticed Win2k3 default font is Tahoma and 2k8 uses Segoe UI, not sure if this is the cause

It's a controlled environment that hosts only my application so changing the windows UI settings is preferable to redesigning all my windows and dialogs.

How can i make my application look the same on win2k8 as it does on win2k3?

Here is an example of my login dialog from the rc file. On win2k8 the text "please enter your user id" wraps over 2 lines and is hidden under the edit box.

```
IDD_LOGON DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 545, 361
STYLE WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE
FONT 8, "Arial"
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "Welcome",IDC_USER_LOGON_HEAD1,368,192,140,19
    LTEXT           "Please enter your User ID",IDC_USER_LOGON_HEAD2,368,220,
                    118,14
    EDITTEXT        IDC_USER_LOGON_USER,368,236,81,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    LTEXT           "and your password",IDC_USER_LOGON_HEAD3,368,260,118,14
    EDITTEXT        IDC_USER_LOGON_PASSWORD,368,276,81,12,ES_PASSWORD | 
                    ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    PUSHBUTTON      "OK",IDOK,368,316,50,14,WS_DISABLED
    PUSHBUTTON      "E&xit",IDCANCEL,424,316,50,14
END
```

edit:

I did some further investigation by taking some screen shots of the above dialog. it appears the problem is not that the text is the wrong size - the problem in the controls on the dialog are too small!

eg:

for the control IDC_USER_LOGON_PASSWORD which is 81 dialog units x 12 dialog units.

it should be rendered as 142 px by 24 px

instead it is rendered too small as 122 px by 21 px

Does this give anyone any clues?

Comment: Can you post some screen shots ? Does the problem occur in dialogs ? Please post an excerpt of your .rc file containing the template on one of the affected dialogs.

Comment: Try to substitute "Arial" by "Ms Shell Dlg". But your problem is quite strange anyway because it seems that your Arial font replaced by some other larger font (possibily Segoe UI ?) on Win2k8. Also try to identify which font is actually displayed on Win2k3 and on Win2k8.

Comment: Also look if there are any suspicious font substitutions in the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes" registry key.

Comment: Smells like a problem with the video adapter DPI setting, although that shouldn't affect dialogs.  Right-click the desktop, Personalize, Display, choose 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Hans, the problem was a DPI setting. The Win2k8 system has a DPI of 96 and the win2k3 system has a DPI of 120.

Setting the DPI on win2k8 to 120 resolves the issue when logged on via remote desktop, however there are still some issues getting citrix settings to respect this DPI settings, but I'm on the right track now.

thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have ["Desktop Experience"](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2576/windows_server_2008_install_desktop_experience_vista_theme/) installed. You can uninstall it, and the server will run in "Classic" mode.

Additionally, you can play with "Personalisation Settings". Open Control panel\Appearance and Personalisation\Display and select "Make text and other items larger or smaller". There you can set the size of each elements. I recommend you set everything at 100%.

Also, if this does not help, you can change Compatibility for the application in Win2k8 to run as Win2k3.

Comment: But even with "Desktop Experience" activated, the font (Arial in our case) should not be substituted by something else, unless Arial is not installed, which is rather unlikely.

Comment: Or maybe there are soime strange font substitutions in the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes" registry key.

Comment: Unfortunate switching to classic mode did not fix the issue. I don't think the font size is the problem either, I took screen grabs and compared them and the font sizes are the same. What has changed is the dialog layout, eg: an edit box 142 x 24 px is incorrectly rendered as 122 x 21 px